# Fastest way to serve Javascript with JSON lookup on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have this javascript file currently served from a Cloud Function on GCP which basically takes a string of products IDs and performs a lookup in a very large JSON object and returns the values.

The JSON object is currently static but I'd like to find a way to have the JSON object updated dynamically once a day.

What would be the best way to accomplish this without sacrificing the fast loading speed of the cloud function? I'm evaluating importing the JSON from a Google cloud storage bucket and then parse, but my experience with Cloud Storage is that is much slower than Cloud Functions.

What are your thoughts?

```
var PRODUCTS = { //long json object of product IDs and properties };

exports.productMargins = (req, res) => {  
  if (req.query['products']) {
    const reqProducts = req.query['products'].split(',');
    const products = reqProducts.map((productId) => {
        return PRODUCTS[productId] || null;
    })
    res.status(200).send(products);
  }
  res.status(200).send([]);
};
```

Comment: What's the problem with your current approach that you're trying to solve. Also note that recommending a technology (or other off-site resource) is off topic on Stack Overflow, so you might want to phrase your question in a way that avoids asking for tha.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Problem is that it is static, I want the JSON to be updated once a day somehow.

Comment: It'll be hard to make something that looks up the JSON from somewhere, but that's as fast as having the JSON in the code. So one thing to consider is to update the JSON in the code once a day, and redeploy the updated code to Cloud Functions. A simple improvement to that would be to store the JSON in a separate file inside the deploy, so that you can rewrite that file